# conversion prediction / ROC curve using markov chains for channel attribution

Tags: r, classification, prediction, markov-process, roc

I am currently working on a project on multi-channel attribution, using the [channel attribution package from Altomare & Loris (2018)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChannelAttribution/index.html), which uses markov chains for attribution. A walk-through of the methodology is described in [this article.](https://analyzecore.com/2016/08/03/attribution-model-r-part-1/)

My plan was to compare their model with two other ones based on their predictive accuracy (predicting conversion 0 or 1), by analyzing their ROC curves (similar to [Anderl, Becker & von Wangenheim, 2016)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167811616300349).

However, I do not know or understand the logic of how i can use the output of the channel attribution package which uses a markov model (giving removal effects, transition matrix, attribution weights) to develop a predictive model of conversion, as is commonly done in the literature (and which can be used in the RCOR package).

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!